# Compare byte in unsigned char with hex, test if file is ELF file

Tags: c, arrays, compare, byte, elf

I need to test if a file is a ELF file, to do this, i have to compare the first four bytes. The first bytes of the files begins with `0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46`.

I use fread(...) to read first four bytes out to an array. Printing the content of the array shows that the file contains the hex numbers described over.

I have tried some easy methods to compare each byte with the hex code, like this

```
if(bytes[0] != "0x7f" || bytes[1] != "0x45 ....) printf("Error, not ELF file")
```

But as i understand, i cant compare bytes this way. Which way should i compare the content in the array to get this correct ?

Comment: The only problem I see with your comparison is you're treating the byte values as if they are strings. Remove the quotes.

Comment: `if(!memcmp(bytes, "\x7F\x45\x4C\x46", 4))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bytes you read are not strings, they are single bytes. So compare e.g. `bytes[0]` with `0x7f` (the integer literal and not the string) or `127` decimal or `0177` octal.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can't compare bytes that way; you're comparing a single character with the pointer to a string literal. Not a lot of right.

You just need to do:

```
if(bytes[0] != 0x7f || bytes[1] != 0x45 || /* more */)
```

Just make sure `bytes` is `unsigned char`.

You can also make it a bit more clear by using a function:

```
const unsigned char header[] = { 0x7f, 0x45, 0x4c, 0x46 };

if(memcmp(bytes, header, sizeof header) != 0)
{
  /* bad header */
}
```